# 'TensorBoard' object has no attribute 'writer' error when using Callback.on_epoch_end()

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

Since Model.train_on_batch() doesn't take a callback input, I tried using Callback.on_epoch_end() in order to write my loss to tensorboard

However, trying to run the on_epoch_end() method results in the titular error, 'TensorBoard' object has no attribute 'writer'. Other solutions to my original problem with writing to tensorboard included calling the Callback.writer attribute, and running these solutions gave the same error. Also, the tensorflow documentation for the TensorBoard class doesn't mention a writer attribute

I'm somewhat of a novice programmer, but it seems to me that the on_epoch_end() method is also at some point calling the writer attribute, but I'm confused as to why the function would use an attribute that doesn't exist

Here's the code I'm using to create the callback:

```
logdir = "./logs/"
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir)
```

and this is the callback code that I try to run in my training loop:

```
logs = {
            'encoder':encoder_loss[0],
            'discriminator':d_loss,
            'generator':g_loss,
        }
tensorboard_callback.on_epoch_end(i, logs)
```

where encoder_loss, d_loss, and g_loss are my scalars, and i is the batch number

Is the error a result of some improper code on my part, or is tensorflow trying to reference something that doesn't exist?

Also, if anyone knows another way to write to tensorboard using Model.train_on_batch, that would also solve my problem

Comment: Same problem here

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a callback without the fit method, you also need to pass your model to the TensorBoard object:

```
logdir = "./logs/"
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir)
tensorboard_callback.set_model(model=model)
```